# Triangle inequalities pertaining to point M inside triangle

Tags: inequality

I spent a lot of time over this problem but made little progress.Here is the problem:

Let M be a point inside a triangle ABC. Here MA=x, MB=y and MC=z
Show that $\frac{(x+y+z)^9}{729xyz} \geq a^2b^2c^2$

My progress: I used AM > GM like this:
$x+y+z > 3(xyz)^{1/3}$

Raising to power of $9$ on both sides, we get
$\frac{(x+y+z)^9}{729xyz}> 27x^2y^2z^2$

We also know that $a+b>x+y$ and so on for interior point $M$.

Comment: what are the $x,y,z$ ? are they the distanced from $M$ to the sides of the triangle ? or $x = MA, y = MB, z = MC$ ?

Comment: Here MA=x, MB=y and MC=z